# HttpOnly vs LocalStorage to store JWT

Tags: security, authentication, cookies, jwt, single-page-application

There are many similar questions here on SO asking about this, but couldn't find one that would address my concerns about using HttpOnly cookies.

There are many answers that suggest using HttpOnly cookies reasoning that an XSS vulnerability on the site would allow an attacker to steal the JWT (or any auth) tokens from the LocalStorage, and this could be prevented by storing the token as a HttpOnly cookie.

I understand that, it kind of makes sense. An attacker with access to a user's auth token can impersonate that user on the targeted website.

However, if a website has an XSS vulnerability then the attacker can already do anything as the user without actually stealing the cookies. It can make requests to the site, steal user data, or perform restricted actions.

**Is there anything an attacker can do with a stolen auth token that is not possible on the site as an XSS?**

**Given the above, is there a reason to prefer using cookies over the LocalStorage to store auth tokens?**

(LocalStorage vs SessionStorage is a separate concern, I'm not necessarily interested in that comparison.)